# App crash on Facebook login using facebook4 plugin for phonegap on android

Tags: java, android, oauth, phonegap-plugins, facebook-login

I have a phonegap hybrid app with Facebook connect plugin. First time when I login then the FB login works but after I logout and then again try to login via Facebook then the app crashes with the following Logcat results :

Plugin  URL : 
https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4

```
06-18 21:31:50.071 3129-3219/? E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0x9b2370a0
06-18 21:31:50.096 3129-3129/? I/Choreographer: Skipped 39 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-18 21:31:50.104 3129-3234/? D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9e677300: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xaa366e80)
06-18 21:31:50.356 3129-3129/? D/CordovaActivity: Incoming Result. Request code = 64206
06-18 21:31:50.356 3129-3129/? D/CordovaInterfaceImpl: Sending activity result to plugin
06-18 21:31:50.356 3129-3129/? D/ConnectPlugin: activity result in plugin: requestCode(64206), resultCode(-1)
06-18 21:31:50.372 3129-3129/? D/com.facebook.FacebookSdk: getGraphApiVersion: v3.0
06-18 21:31:50.372 3129-3129/? D/com.facebook.FacebookSdk: getGraphApiVersion: v3.0
06-18 21:31:50.378 3129-3129/? D/CordovaActivity: Resumed the activity.
06-18 21:31:50.379 3129-3129/? W/com.facebook.appevents.AppEventsLogger: activateApp events are being logged automatically. There's no need to call activateApp explicitly, this is safe to remove.
06-18 21:31:50.551 3129-3219/? E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0x98eed520
06-18 21:31:51.043 3129-3129/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM


                                                 --------- beginning of crash
06-18 21:31:51.044 3129-3129/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                 Process: com.sqlchild.app1, PID: 3129
                                                 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.indexOf(int)' on a null object reference
                                                     at libcore.net.UriCodec.decode(UriCodec.java:153)
                                                     at java.net.URLDecoder.decode(URLDecoder.java:60)
                                                     at org.apache.cordova.facebook.ConnectPlugin.makeGraphCall(ConnectPlugin.java:751)
                                                     at org.apache.cordova.facebook.ConnectPlugin.access$200(ConnectPlugin.java:55)
                                                     at org.apache.cordova.facebook.ConnectPlugin$2$1.onCompleted(ConnectPlugin.java:111)
                                                     at com.facebook.GraphRequest$1.onCompleted(GraphRequest.java:301)
                                                     at com.facebook.GraphRequest$5.run(GraphRequest.java:1380)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
06-18 21:31:51.052 1667-2063/? W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.sqlchild.app1/.MainActivity
06-18 21:31:51.067 1259-1321/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: Creating ashmem region of size 589824


                                                 [ 06-18 21:31:51.097  1667: 2063 D/         ]
                                                 HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x9aa0cc00, tid 2063


                                                 [ 06-18 21:31:51.099  1667: 2063 W/         ]
                                                 Unrecognized GLES max version string in extensions: ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 
06-18 21:31:51.113 1259-1259/? E/EGL_emulation: tid 1259: eglCreateSyncKHR(1881): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)
06-18 21:31:51.199 1667-1667/? W/art: Long monitor contention event with owner method=void com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.crashApplication(com.android.server.am.ProcessRecord, android.app.ApplicationErrorReport$CrashInfo) from ActivityManagerService.java:12502 waiters=0 for 133ms
06-18 21:31:51.289 1667-1677/? I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 36018(2MB) AllocSpace objects, 1(20KB) LOS objects, 33% free, 7MB/11MB, paused 3.358ms total 105.317ms
06-18 21:31:51.381 1667-1729/? I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
06-18 21:31:51.390 1667-1729/? D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xa07fc120: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
06-18 21:31:51.414 1667-1729/? D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa07fc120: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa0ea42f0)
06-18 21:31:51.484 1667-1729/? D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa07fc120: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa0ea42f0)
06-18 21:31:51.691 1667-3205/? I/AccountManagerService: getTypesVisibleToCaller: isPermitted? true
06-18 21:31:51.698 1667-1683/? W/ActivityManager: Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{21fdafb u0 com.sqlchild.app1/.MainActivity t8 f}
06-18 21:31:51.877 1667-3206/? W/art: Long monitor contention event with owner method=void com.android.server.am.ActivityStack$ActivityStackHandler.handleMessage(android.os.Message) from ActivityStack.java:283 waiters=0 for 175ms
06-18 21:31:51.896 1667-1683/? I/ActivityManager: Killing 2545:com.android.keychain/1000 (adj 15): empty #17
06-18 21:31:52.070 2029-2239/? D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xae594600: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xae5924b0)
06-18 21:31:59.062 3129-3129/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 3129 SIG: 9
06-18 21:31:59.075 1667-1729/? D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa07fc120: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa0ea42f0)
06-18 21:31:59.079 1667-1729/? E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0x9e8d1360
06-18 21:31:59.128 1667-3206/? E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 104)
06-18 21:31:59.130 1667-1721/? W/InputDispatcher: channel '7f56d84 com.sqlchild.app1/com.sqlchild.app1.MainActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
06-18 21:31:59.130 1667-1721/? E/InputDispatcher: channel '7f56d84 com.sqlchild.app1/com.sqlchild.app1.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
06-18 21:31:59.129 1667-3206/? W/InputMethodManagerService: Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 3129 uid 10061
06-18 21:31:59.132 1667-1721/? W/InputDispatcher: channel 'e76402c com.sqlchild.app1/com.facebook.FacebookActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
06-18 21:31:59.133 1667-1721/? E/InputDispatcher: channel 'e76402c com.sqlchild.app1/com.facebook.FacebookActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
06-18 21:31:59.153 1667-3206/? E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 104)
06-18 21:31:59.168 1667-1680/? I/WindowState: WIN DEATH: Window{e76402c u0 com.sqlchild.app1/com.facebook.FacebookActivity}
06-18 21:31:59.169 1667-1680/? W/InputDispatcher: Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel 'e76402c com.sqlchild.app1/com.facebook.FacebookActivity (server)'
06-18 21:31:59.174 1667-2280/? D/GraphicsStats: Buffer count: 3
06-18 21:31:59.207 1667-1681/? I/ActivityManager: Process com.sqlchild.app1 (pid 3129) has died
06-18 21:31:59.257 1667-3110/? I/WindowState: WIN DEATH: Window{7f56d84 u0 com.sqlchild.app1/com.sqlchild.app1.MainActivity}
06-18 21:31:59.257 1667-3110/? W/InputDispatcher: Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel '7f56d84 com.sqlchild.app1/com.sqlchild.app1.MainActivity (server)'
```